# DataGridView: How do I write the first added row to a file?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The following code is supposed to write the DataGridView data source to a delimited text file when the two columns of the current row (the row to be added) have data. Whether the two columns of the current row have data is checked when the CellEndEdit event is triggered.

- In practice, when the two columns of the initial current row have data, the initial current row is NOT written to the delimited text file.
- When the two columns of subsequent current rows have data, the subsequent current rows ARE written to the delimited text file.
- The initial current row is never written to the delimited text file.

How can I get the initial current row to write to the destination as expected?

```
private void dataGridRecord_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var currentRow = dataGridRecord.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    if (currentRow.Cells.Count > 0)
    {
        bool partialStringRecord = false;

        // Determine how many of the row's cells are empty
        int emptyCells = currentRow.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
            .Count(cell => cell.Value == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.Value.ToString()));

        // If only one of the two cells is empty, the record is incomplete
        if (emptyCells == 1) partialStringRecord = true;

        // If the record is incomplete, prevent adding new rows...
        if (partialStringRecord)
        {
            dataGridRecord.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            return;
        }

        // ...until the columns of the current row have data
        dataGridRecord.AllowUserToAddRows = true;

        // Write data table to file
        var table = (DataTable)dataGridRecord.DataSource;
        var records = FileManager.ToStringRecordList(table);
        FileManager.SaveCsvFile(records, _fileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I came up with:

```
private void dataGridRecord_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var rows = dataGridRecord.Rows;
    var emptyCells = rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
        .Count(cell => cell.Value == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.Value.ToString()));

    // if there are no partial records
    if (emptyCells == 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
        {
            rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            rows[i].ReadOnly = false;
        }

        FileManager.SaveDataTableToCsvFile(dataGridRecord, _fileName);
    }
    // if there are partial records
    else
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex != 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
            {
                // highlight current row and disable other rows
                if (rows[i] == rows[e.RowIndex])
                {
                    rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
                    rows[i].ReadOnly = false;
                }
                else if (rows[i] != rows[e.RowIndex])
                {
                    rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                    rows[i].ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FileManager.SaveDataTableToCsvFile(dataGridRecord, _fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Probably unwieldy when many thousands of records are loaded. We'll see.